# cannot connect SQL server 2014 express with eclipse

Tags: java, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2014-express

I am using SQL server 2014 express edition with java  jdk 11.0.1 and jre 8.0.191
.I tried to download JDBC driver but cannot find the suitable one that is compatible with the SQL serve 2014.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have used the [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774) to download the jdbc driver and it works only  when we put the version of the server as SQL Server 2008 while selecting the version of the server used.

I don't know why it is not working when i select the version as SQL server 2014 and also we need to add the library of **Connectivity Driver Definition**  in order to compile JDBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the official Microsoft JDBC drivers for SQL Server (including 2014):
[Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)